# Show that $x^3-\sqrt[ ]{3}$ is irreducible in $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[4]{3})$

Tags: abstract-algebra

*Show that $x^3-\sqrt[ ]{3}$ is irreducible in $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[4]{3})$*

I suppose it is reducible and write:

$x^3-\sqrt[ ]{3}=(x-a)(x^2+bx+c)$

Then I solve the system of equations and get $a=\sqrt[6]{3}$

Now I should prove that $\sqrt[6]{3}\notin \mathbb Q(\sqrt[4]{3})$. But how to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

$x^3-\sqrt{3}$ is reducible over $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[4]{3})$ iff it has a root in $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[4]{3})$.

If $\theta \in \mathbb C$ is a root of $x^3-\sqrt{3}$, then $\theta^6=3$ and so $\theta$ is a root of $x^6-3$, which is irreducible over $\mathbb Q$ by Eisenstein's criterion. Therefore, $\theta$ has degree $6$ over $\mathbb Q$ and so cannot be an element of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[4]{3})$ since this extension has degree $4$.

Comment: Thanks, good point. I still would want to know how to prove that $\sqrt[6]{3}\notin \mathbb Q(\sqrt[4]{3})$....

Comment: The argument above is a proof that $\sqrt[6]{3}\notin \mathbb Q(\sqrt[4]{3})$.